Convert Array of single dynamic-key objects into a single object representing all dynamic key entries
Assuming we have the following array structure of n length:
const sourceArray = [
  { "dynamicKey1": true },
  { "dynamicKey2": false },
  { "dynamicKey3": true },
  ...
]


How could I tersely reduce this array to a single object of dynamic length:
const convertedObj = {
  "dynamicKey1": true,
  "dynamicKey2": false,
  "dynamicKey3": true
  ...
}

Thanks!

You can achieve this using Array.prototype.reduce() and  Object.assign() to merge curr into acc (starts of as {} initially), copying the key-value pairs.:


const sourceArray = [
  { "dynamicKey1": true },
  { "dynamicKey2": false },
  { "dynamicKey3": true }
];
const convertedObj = sourceArray.reduce((acc, curr) => Object.assign(acc, curr), {});
console.log(convertedObj);




You could spread the array directly into Object.assign with an empty object as target.


const
    sourceArray = [{ "dynamicKey1": true }, { "dynamicKey2": false }, { "dynamicKey3": true }],
    convertedObject = Object.assign({}, ...sourceArray);

console.log(convertedObject);




Use reduce and ... to spread the object in array.


const sourceArray = [{ dynamicKey1: true }, { dynamicKey2: false }, { dynamicKey3: true }];

const convertedObj = sourceArray.reduce((acc, _) => ({ ...acc, ..._ }), {});

console.log(convertedObj);




const sourceArray = [
  { "dynamicKey1": true },
  { "dynamicKey2": false },
  { "dynamicKey3": true }
]

const convertedObj = {};

sourceArray.forEach((v, i) => {for(let key in v){convertedObj[key]= v[key]}});

convertedObj

{"dynamicKey1": true, "dynamicKey2": false, "dynamicKey3": true}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
